# Unable to see join nodes in Kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

This is my worker node:

```
root@ivu:~# kubeadm join 10.16.70.174:6443 --token hl36mu.0uptj0rp3x1lfw6n --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:daac28160d160f938b82b8c720cfc91dd9e6988d743306f3aecb42e4fb114f19 --ignore-preflight-errors=swap
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
        [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
        [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "10.16.70.174:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://10.16.70.174:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https://10.16.70.174:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server "10.16.70.174:6443"
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "10.16.70.174:6443"

This node has joined the cluster:
* Certificate signing request was sent to master and a response
  was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this node join the cluster.
```

While checking in master nodes using command `kubectl get nodes`, I can only able to see master:

```
ivum01@ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                     STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ivum01-hp-pro-3330-sff   Ready     master    36m       v1.10.0
```

---

For question answer:

1. docker kubelet kubeadm kubectl installed fine
2. `kubectl get node` can not see the current added node; of cause `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` has no result for this node;
3. `docker` which in current node has no report for `kubeadm` command(means no k8s images pull, no running container for that)
4. must import is `kubelet` not running in work node
5. run `kubelet` output:

   > Failed to get system container stats for "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope": failed to get cgroup stats for "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope": failed to get container info for "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope": unknown container "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope"

   same as [this issue said](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57080)
6. tear down and reset cluster(`kubeadm reset`) and redo that has no problem in my case.

Comment: Can you check, is `kubelet` running on your node and show a list of active docker containers?

Comment: Hi  Anton , As I am new to kubernetes ,please share me the command to check kubelet details .

Comment: I typed sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces command and able to see all the pods are running .

Comment: Ok. Can you check `kubectl get nodes` output one more time? I don't see any errors in logs and it should works. And check which containers are running now on your node by `docker ps` command.

Comment: Its only showing master ,same as above . All kube system related containers are running ..I followed https://blog.tekspace.io/setup-kubernetes-cluster-with-ubuntu-16-04/ for set up.

Comment: What about the list of containers on your node, not on the master? Show `docker ps` result.

Comment: BTW, if you have only one server (for example - your workstation) - use [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) instead of `kubeadm`. It will prepare a ready-to-use cluster for you right on your server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was solved by ensuring that cgroup driver on the *worker* nodes also were set properly.

check with:

```
docker info | grep -i cgroup
cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

set it with:

```
sed -i "s/cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=cgroupfs/g" /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

then restart kubelet service and rejoin the cluster:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
kubeadm reset
kubeadm join ...
```

Info from docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubeadm/#configure-cgroup-driver-used-by-kubelet-on-master-node